# How do I update controller param to accept nested attributes with rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on a rails app, I was wondering how to update controller params to accept nested attributes with rails, this is the existing controller;

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_shop_shipping_options, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['shipping_option_id'].blank? }
```

```
 def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(
      :sku, :name, :shipping_option_id, :product_region_id
    )
  end
```

I was wondering if I need to add a different attribute, do I do it with create or update method in controller?

Answer (score 2):

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :variants
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :image
end
```

Add accepts_nested_attributes_for followed by name of associated model . In my case its image .

In controller you have to add below code :

```
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(
   :name, :price,
   image_attributes: [ :id, :url, :alt, :caption ]
 )
end
```

In your case it will become

```
def product_params 
  params.require(:product).permit(
   :sku, :name, 
   product_shop_shipping_options_attributes: [ :shipping_option_id, :product_region_id] 
  )
end
```

Comment: hi!! thank you! I've updated the question, what do you think I can update my param? thanks!

Comment: Because i think i alreay have it as shipping_option_id, haven't I?

Comment: add params of  product_shop_shipping_options model .

Comment: @developing I have updated the answer . please check and vote if it works for you .

Comment: hi !!thanks! I was wondering - what does this line of code means? product_shop_shipping_options _attributes

Comment: and there's a gap in between product_shop_shipping_options and _attributes,  why?

Comment: @developing it was typo . It means you are adding attributes of associated model

Comment: @developing what do you exactly want to implement ?